# Create a bootstrap that passes arguments to the msiexec

Tags: wix, wix3, bootstrapping, silent-installer

I need to create a bootstrap for my WiX project I've tried using **setupbld.exe** but it will only allow me to create an executable that will show my UI or one that will behave as a silent installer but not both.

I need to be able to run the resulting executable with argument that will tell it wether or not to show the UI during installation.

I've found this [post by John Robbins](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/02/27/creating-a-bootstrap-loader-with-wix-3-0.aspx) that explains how to re-build the setup.exe stub used in the creation of the bootstrap but I was hoping there is a simpler way to do what I need.

Does anyone know of a way to create a bootstrap that I use to run either as a simple (with UI) install or as a silent install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AT the end I've used 7zip to zip the MSI in a self extracting archive.
You can add a "config" file to let 7zip which files to run when opening the executable.

Check out [7zip's manual for more details](http://www.downloadatoz.com/utility_directory/7-zip/manual/cmdline/switches/sfx.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I've seen [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) recommended on the [WiX](http://wix.sf.net) mailing list a lot, should be a lot more flexible than `setupbld.exe` but I haven't used it myself.

**Update:** If you've got budget to purchase software, try the bootstrapper that comes with [MSI Factory](http://www.indigorose.com/products/msi-factory/) (the demo just displays a nag screen before launching the bootstrapper). We use this ourselves and it's been worth every penny.

Comment: Try `irmakebootstrap` which comes with MSI Factory - http://www.indigorose.com/products/msi-factory/